# Tearaway footer not working

Tags: html, css

I made an html `<footer>` on my website. But when they were too few content, the footer was sticked to the content.

[image: explanation]

So i followed the tutorial [here](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/), but the footer "collapses" anyway. Here is my page: http://polar-wave-4072.herokuapp.com/help

http://jsfiddle.net/mL4xL/

Comment: Please get all relevant code and create a JSFiddle, also these are tons more of tutorials on this. You are looking for [**sticky footer**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).

Comment: How about min-height attribute??

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/mL4xL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to add 100% height to **html** element.

```
body,html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Thhank you it it "temporary". Now the footer "flies". http://jsfiddle.net/mL4xL/2/

Answer (score -1):

If you include [**min-height**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) attribute through jquery it will work for all devices like responsive

```
$('#content').css('min-height',$(window).height()-240)
```

Your code will looks like

Include this into document.ready section and go

Working example could be found here http://jsbin.com/roboqobo/1/